# How to set dynamic width for parent depending on image width using only css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am creating my own lightbox with React and I want to set width on div with class `.lightbox-active` depending on image width. For now, I have set `max-width: 50%; max-height: 80%` for parent element and when e.g. the image is filling only 43% of parent element I want to set 43% width for a parent. Is there any way to achieve this without calculating the width in js?

```
<div className="lightbox-active">
  <img onLoad={() => isFinished()} src={fakeImages[openedImage - 1].url} alt="" />
</div>
```

My image has got property `object-fit: contain` and I need this for display image in original proportions, without this image is filling 50% width as it's parent but overflowing height.

Working example:

https://codepen.io/freestyle09/pen/rNNdNNg

Border green should have sizes like an image

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.lightbox-active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.lightbox-active img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="lightbox-active">
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/1503/1500' alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add the content as code snippet

Comment: Edited for code snippet

Comment: @Freestyle09 See my answer, it can work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, which can be achieved using `position: absolute` . It can work for you as you want.

You have to modify the css of `.lightbox-active` and `.lightbox-active img` to use absolute positioning.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.lightbox-active {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.lightbox-active img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="lightbox-active">
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/1503/1500' alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice work :) I didn't think about position absolute :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using inline block and overflow hidden can solve your issue to some extent. But the image will be cropped at the bottom if image is larger than available space.

Refer the code snippet below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.lightbox-active {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.lightbox-active img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="lightbox-active">
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/1503/1500' alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```